# How to group columns based on date? XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms.listview

In my program, I load the entire table and I would like to group all columns based on date. I don't know how to do it in xaml. Sorry for my english. My table looks like this:

[image]

can something be achieved from this level of the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CollectionViewSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource?view=net-5.0) to Sort, Filter and Group your data and then bind it to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`.

Check the following articles:

[How to: Group Items in a ListView That Implements a GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-items-in-a-listview-that-implements-a-gridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

[ListView grouping](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)